# Inserting byte array vs Encoded text in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I get stream of BSON data in my WebApi. I need to store the stream into database.
Should I store the data in varbinary column or encode the data into UTF8 encoding & then save?

I am using entity framework for data access.
If you suggest saving in binary, which data type should be preferred **binary** or **byte**?

Comment: If you have *arbitrary* binary data, converting it (directly) to UTF8 is wrong. You should be thinking (if you want to go the text route) of Base-64 encoding or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSON is binary. You should ideally store it in a `varbinary(...)` column (`varbinary(max)` is the most convenient). Do not consider UTF-8: it is **incorrect** to use UTF-8 to convert arbitrary binary to a string; that is *encoding backwards* and the [only guaranteed output is corrupt data](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html). If you **must** store binary in a character-based field (`[n][var]char(...)`), then use base-64.